# Trying to run a simple dynamic scaffolding Grails app results in an ORA-00904 error

Tags: java, database, oracle, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD for a table in an Oracle 12 database so I created a Grails application, passed the database credentials in `application.yml`, created a controller and domain class named `ConfigTest` (the column is called `CONFIG_TEST` in the actual DB) and added some simple code to them.

The domain class:

```
package moduleprototype

class ConfigTest {
    int configid
    String name
    String type
    String value
    String description
    int status

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
package moduleprototype

class ConfigTestController {

    static scaffold = ConfigTest
}
```

The columns in my table are:

- CONFIGID `NUMBER`
- NAME `VARCHAR2`
- TYPE `VARCHAR2`
- VALUE `CLOB`
- DESCRIPTION `VARCHAR2`
- STATUS `NUMBER`

Thus, it looks like it should work but when I run the app and go to `http://localhost:8080/ConfigTest`, I get:

> 2019-01-08 15:06:28.552 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00904:
>   "THIS_"."VERSION": invalid identifier
>
> 2019-01-08 15:06:28.856 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : OracleDatabaseException
>   occurred when processing request: [GET] /ConfigTest ORA-00904:
>   "THIS_"."VERSION": invalid identifier

Why is that so? What am I doing wrong? From what I gathered, errors like these are usually connected to naming problems but here, it seems like the names are OK and the model also follows the Grails name processing principles (or so it seems).

EDIT: I've also tried to do custom static mapping so as to be sure that everything maps to what I thought it did so I added this to the model class:

```
static mapping = {
    table 'CONFIG_TEST'

    configid column: 'CONFIGID'
    name column: 'NAME'
    type column: 'TYPE'
    value column: 'VALUE'
    description column: 'DESCRIPTION'
    status column: 'STATUS'

}
```

But it does not help at all, the same error persists :(

Comment: Guessing you manually created your database table? i.e. Grails didn't do it. Grails expects a column named version unless you tell it not to bother, see http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/version.html, it looks like Grails is running a query on your domain and expecting a version column

Comment: @MikeW - yep, you're right! Regretfully, adding `version false` to the mapping section only changes the first part of the error to `ORA-00904: "THIS_"."ID":` instead of `"THIS_"."VERSION"` but the effect is still the same and the app still doesn't want to run properly :(

Comment: Grails also expects an `ID` column. But you can remap it to a different column, see the last example: https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html

Comment: @kfinity - ah, ok, thanks! Did just that, added a line remapping ID to the CONFIGID I have in my DB like this: `id column: 'configid', type: 'integer'` but this now results in yet another error, namely `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` :( None of my columns have the same name as can be seen in the list above so why is that happening?

Comment: OK, solved that last problem by changing the `id column` part to `id column: 'CONFIGID', name:'configid',  type: 'integer'`! Thanks a lot to you both @kfinity , @MikeW - if any of you want to upgrade your comments to an answer, I'll gladly upvote and accept them :)

Comment: Answer added, I hate seeing questions with answers in comments, honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails expects a column named version on your table unless you disable it in the mapping block in your domain class like:

```
static mapping = {
    version false
}
```

The version column is used for optimistic locking.

See [the docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/version.html) for full info.